# How to get gradle to detect my test classes

Tags: eclipse, spring, junit4, build.gradle

I am using Springs Eclipse environment and Gradle to build my project.

I am executing gradles "test" target and get the following output:

```
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
```

But gradle does not find my test classes. I have tried with adding this to build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
test {

        testClassesDir = "build/classes/test"
        testSrcDirs = "src/main/java"

        }
}
```

My test classes are in the folder "src/main/java/junit

How is the best way to get gradle to detect my test classes? Should I move them to another folder which gradle automatically serach or is it the sourceSets that is the way forward, and what am I doing wrong with sourceSets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add dependency such as:-

```
dependencies {
    testCompile(group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11')
}
```

And use the directory structure as- "src/test/java"
In my case it works.